# SKAction: scaleTo:1.0 duration .01, is there a way to make "duration" any faster/instant? Objective C, Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to get the duration of this SKAction down to pretty much nothing. The reason is this action subtracts the users coins, and though .01 is pretty fast, it is still not instant and the user cannot make a move while the coins are subtracting. Is there anyways to "instantly" perform this SKAction?

```
            NSLog(@"SubtractUserCoinsActivated");
            int a = USER_COINS;
            int result = a - 49;
            [self setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
            __block int dummyScore = a;
            SKAction* scaleUp = [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:0.01];
            SKAction* block = [SKAction runBlock:^{
                dummyScore--;
                _userCoinsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dummyScore];
                if(dummyScore == result) {
                    [_defaults setInteger:result forKey:@"UserCoins"];
                    [_defaults synchronize];
                    NSLog(@"-49 Coins");
                    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
```

Comment: im confused.. why use an action at all if you want it instant?  why not just set the scale to 1?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an instant SKAction, just set the duration to 0.0 instead of 0.01 .

I do it all the time. I program in Swift, but it should be the same in Objective-C

E.g. in my code right now I have a scale action that uses a duration of zero

```
let scale:SKAction = SKAction.scaleTo(0, duration: 0.0)
```